# I am looking for a type of react carousel

Tags: css, reactjs, package, slider, carousel

Is there any package of  carousel like this?

[the carousel I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDGcr.png)

If the slider switches, the image on the far right will fade out to the right, while the image on the left will fade in

I can't find any carousel like this, please. I don't have much time to customed one.